# How can I trigger the touch keyboard in the guest in VirtualBox full screen mode on an Windows 8.1 Surface host?

Tags: windows-8, virtualbox, keyboard

Running VirtualBox on a Windows 8.1 Surface host, I am running a Windows XP guest with guest additions installed.

When I have my Virtual Box machine in windowed mode I can tap the touch keyboard icon in my Windows 8 task bar to pull up the keyboard.

Is there any way I can pull up the keyboard as needed while in full screen mode where the Windows 8 task bar is of course hidden? Can I trigger a host program using the host key? I’m new to VirtualBox and not sure how to go about this.

Comment: by hotkey I mean shortcut key or key combination

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guess what, next to impossible.

The way the *modern/metro* touch keyboard is implemented does not allow applications to explicitly show it. It's true, I'm not making this up:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465404.aspx#user-driven_invocation

Additionally, when you're in full-screen mode, overlaying something like an on-screen keyboard *from the host* will almost certainly cause problems:

> Many desktop games will be written using full-screen exclusive mode.  This presents a problem when using the built-in keyboards, because either the invoked keyboard will be hidden, or raising the keyboard will force the game out of full-screen mode. https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2013/06/11/touch-keyboard-access-for-windows-8-desktop-apps

I know the above article talks about games but the concept is the same, exclusive full-screen desktop apps don't like sharing the display (or more accurately, they can't).

Anyway, in the end, you might as well just use the On-Screen Keyboard provided within the Windows XP guest itself:

[image: Find the On-Screen Keyboard in the Start Menu]

[image: On-Screen Keyboard]